# How do I expand DisclosureGroup without shifting other elements?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a drop down menu with a DisclosureGroup. Currently it shifts other elements when expanded. How do I get the menu to expand over the other elements rather than moving/resizing them? I though perhaps I could use a Ztack, but I don't know how I would be able to pull that off while preserving the vertical order of my view. I have simplified all of the irrelevant code for the sake of this question. Please let me know if you'd like to see additional code.

**View (simplified)**

```
VStack {
            Text(...)
            
            Image(...)
            
            DisclosureGroup("\(dropdownTitle)", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(plans_controller.plans) { plan in
                        Text(plan.name).font(.title3)
                            .padding(.all)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedPlan = plan.id
                                self.dropdownTitle = plan.name
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }.accentColor(.white)
            .font(.title2)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.all)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            
            
            NavigationLink(...)    // New Plan "button"
            
            Button(...)    //Submit Image button
            
}
```

**App Screenshots (please ignore the horrible UI)**

[image: Normal] [image: Expanded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess for this is to indeed use a ZStack, however you're going to need some things in place to help preserve ordering/scaling as you're expecting. In this example I've wrapped everything inside of a `GeometryReader` so that I can get the height dimensions. Once I have that I can scale each of the stacks according to whatever portion of the screen you want each view to take up.

Then you combine the two and make sure to scale each independently of the other. You may have to play around with the frames to get them lined up the way you want but it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    GeometryReader { geo in 
        VStack {
            //Title
            //Image
        }.frame(height: geo.size.height 0.8)

        VStack { 
            Spacer()
            VStack {
               //Select Plan
               //New Plan
               //Submit Image
            }
            .frame(height: geo.size.height * 0.2)
            //Setting this zIndex may not be required because this is drawn last.
            .zIndex(1.0)
        //NOTICE THIS we are setting the frame for this VStack to match the parent
        //without it, your view will not be put at the bottom of the stack.
        }.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The dropdown was now shifting the 2 buttons below it with your example, but the info you provided was more than enough to tweak it on my own!